# Samsung S22 not showing notifications from android app

Tags: android, android-notifications, samsung-galaxy, android-13

Recently a bunch of customers complained about notifications of our android app not shown and all of them were using a Samsung S22 with Android 13. The push notifications as well as notifications triggered by background service both are affected .The users complained that notifications work for a while when they reinstall the app and after sometime they again stop showing up.

I thought it might be due to the new notification permission in android 13 but it was not the case. Tried switching the battery optimization too but didn't work.

Then I got to know many users are facing this notifications issue for other apps too however could not find a way to resolve the issue. Does anyone know of a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In android 13, You need to request the new notification permission from your app

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Tried that already, still not working

Comment: @PraveshSingh would you try changing compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to version 33

Comment: Tried it already but didn't work. Thanks for your suggestions, I think I have found the solution, mentioning it below.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung phones have an option of background usage limits in settings. I added my app to never sleeping apps and voila the notifications were back.